# Kernel-space: can .probe be called simultaneously/concurrently?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree, probe

I have a simple kernel module for embedded ARM-based system associated with it's **.compatible**. As we know, multiple **".compatibles"** can occur in one device tree and **.probe** will be called for each matched OF node.
I can't find accurate information whether the **.probe** function *can be called simultaneously* by kernel (!) or *not* in case more than one appropriate **.compatible** appear in device tree. Neither reading kernel drivers sources gives me confidence that it can't (be called simultaneously) despite I haven't seen locks in **.probes**.

From [Linux design patterns](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/design-patterns.txt), I've read:

> While the kernel contains a few device drivers that assume that they will
> only be probed() once on a certain system (singletons), it is custom to assume
> that the device the driver binds to will appear in several instances. This
> means that the probe() function and all callbacks need to be reentrant.

But this looks like related to hot plug or something like this (correct me if I'm wrong) while my question is about processing OF nodes only.
I've found there is **.probe_type** which can be set to **PROBE_PREFER_ASYNCHRONOUS** in **platform_driver.driver**, but not sure if it is about what I need (correct me if I'm wrong).
If **.probe** can be called synchronously/concurrently I have to implement some locking and finally make this routine re-entrant.
Can someone, please, point me to link/document/chapter where I can read about how **.probe** mechanism is implemented or give me the exact answer.

Comment: Most all `.probe()` are re-entrant.  You call `kmalloc()`  (ultimately) to make a device structure.  All state should be in the device structure.  There shouldn't be anything in the driver. [Driver design patterns](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/driver-model/design-patterns.html).  Maybe you really want `module_init()`, which is only called once per driver to setup some lookup table or other 'dynamically' initialized system-wide data structure.

Comment: You don’t need a locking to access per-device data, only in case if you have per-driver data, I.e. global variables in it, which is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for my case was simple:

**.probe_type = PROBE_FORCE_SYNCHRONOUS**

will make kernel call **.probes** one by one on each of_node found.

**.probe_type = PROBE_PREFER_ASYNCHRONOUS**

will make kernel call **.probes** concurrently.

How did I get to it. I couldn't find that information in documentation or on blogs/forums. So I've made one second delay in my .probe function, added two of_nodes with my .compatible to my DT and tested it in both cases (PROBE_FORCE_SYNCHRONOUS and PROBE_PREFER_ASYNCHRONOUS) by measuring time insmod takes to load module.

Results of these test look clear: PROBE_FORCE_SYNCHRONOUS takes two seconds to load module, while PROBE_PREFER_ASYNCHRONOUS takes one second.

So, the answer is: yes, .probes can be called concurrently, but we have mechanism to control it.

BTW, thank you for your replies